# babel interfering with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, babel

Consider this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[latvian]{babel}                                                                                                                                                                                
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate(A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate(B) at (1, 1);
  \coordinate(C) at (1, 0);
  \draw   pic [draw, "$\theta_{p}$" font=\tiny] {angle=A--B--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the line

```
%\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
```

I get an error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \theta 
l.12     "$\theta_{p}$" font=\tiny]
                                    {angle=A--B--C};
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

The solution proposed by @marmot works in an article. Now, consider the same example in beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes, babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate(A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate(B) at (1, 1);
    \coordinate(C) at (1, 0);
    \draw   pic [draw, "$\theta_{p}$" font=\tiny] {angle=A--B--C};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

We get a similar problem even when using tikz library `babel`:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dic
tionary-English.dict) (./latvianpres.nav)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \theta 
l.13 \end{frame}
```

Comment: Use the tikzlibrary babel: `\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes,babel}`,

Comment: @marmot please see an update of my question regarding your solution in `beamer`

Comment: It's more of a beamer interference problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Viesturs The solution proposed by @ marmot works fine, you just need a `fragile` frame

Comment: Somebody is welcome to provide the complete answer

Comment: @marmot I found some duplicates for the two problems - have fun in your meeting!